# Gravity Forms After Submission - GFFormsModel::update_lead_field_value?

Tags: functions, forms

I am working with Gravity Forms. This code works with a couple issues :

```
add_action('gform_after_submission_14', 'post_contract_update', 10, 2);
function post_contract_update($entry, $form) {
    $form ='3';
    $lead = $entry['4'];
    $statusvalue_update = 'Under Contract';
    GFFormsModel::update_lead_field_value($form, $lead, '', '', 154, $statusvalue_update);
}
```

After form 14 is fired, it does what it is supposed to using Gravity Forms Model : update_lead_field_value.

Only problem is - once my $lead (lead_id) goes over 9, to a double digit, the entry gets truncated. So for example, in this image below, I actually put in 448 into $lead. In the DB it's only showing as 4.

[image: Gravity forms sql shown]

The storage field is correct int 10 - and adding directly via sql works. So far I have -

- added directly via PHP
- move firing of the function around
- changed priority
- changed themes just in case
- deactivated plugins just in case
- single qouting, double qouting
- printed out array - everything looks perfect
- change string to intval etc...

Nothing seems to work, no matter what - once my $lead id goes above a single digit.

Am I missing something incredibly easy? Am I unaware of limitations on GFFormsModel::update_lead_field_value? Is the model expecting some specific number format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going to close this and answer myself.

Apparently, there is something wrong with the way that GFFormsModel::update_lead_field_value truncates fields. I was unable to get this to work.

Instead - I opted to use a direct WP insert (with if elseif etc...) - like so :

```
$csql = $wpdb->insert("wp_rg_lead_detail", array("id" => NULL,"lead_id" => $lead,"form_id" => $form,"field_number" => "154","value" => 'value'));
```

Not what I wanted to do, but hopefully this will save anyone some time and effort if they run into the same issue with this model.